# Make several sliders/carousels on one page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

I'm using "Datalife Engine" CMS with "Entreprise" template. There is a slider, which adds on the page like this

```
<div id="slider-wrapper">
<div class="slider">
    <div class="slide" style="background-image: url(/uploads/fotos/lager.jpg);">
        <div class="cnt">
            <div class="slide-text">
                <h2>Duis felis tortor, consequat</h2>
                <p>Duis felis tortor, consequat In sed elementum risus. Phasellus venenatis hendrerit pharetra. Suspendisse ultricies malesuada metus, non placerat lectus pellentesque at. Vivamus ut molestie lorem, non bibendum neque. Nam sagittis luctus egestas. Donec libero turpis, faucibus vitae iaculis vel, mattis at tortor.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide" style="background-image: url(/uploads/fotos/day_lager.jpg);">
        <div class="cnt">
            <div class="slide-text right-text">
                <h2>Phasellus venenatis hendrerit pharetra</h2>
                <p>Duis felis tortor, consequat In sed elementum risus. Phasellus venenatis hendrerit pharetra. Suspendisse ultricies malesuada metus, non placerat lectus pellentesque at. Vivamus ut molestie lorem, non bibendum neque. Nam sagittis luctus egestas. Donec libero turpis, faucibus vitae iaculis vel, mattis at tortor.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<span class="slider-button slider-button-prev"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></span>
<span class="slider-button slider-button-next"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></span>
```

The slider runs with this JS(i think)

```
$(".slider").aSlider({
    prevBtn: '.slider-button-prev',
    nextBtn: '.slider-button-next',
    fadeSpeed: 500, // скорость затухания/появления слайда
    autoPlay: true, // автоперелистывание слайдов (true/false)
    autoPlayDelay: 5000, // время показа в слайдах в миллисекундах
    slideDelay: 500
});
```

This is aSlider function

```
/* jQuery aSlider v1.2 */
;
! function (e) {
    jQuery.fn.aSlider = function (a) {
        var a = e.extend({
                nextBtn: ".aSliderNext",
                prevBtn: ".aSliderPrev",
                fadeSpeed: 300,
                autoPlay: !1,
                autoPlayDelay: 3e3,
                slideDelay: 0
            }, a),
            d = function () {
                function d() {
                    e(a.nextBtn).click(), r = setTimeout(d, a.autoPlayDelay)
                }
                var t = e(this),
                    n = t.children(".slide:first-child"),
                    l = t.children(".slide:last-child"),
                    i = n.index(),
                    f = l.index(),
                    u = n;
                if (t.css("overflow", "hidden"), t.find(".slide").fadeOut(0), n.fadeIn(0), e(a.nextBtn).click(function (e) {
                        return e.preventDefault(), u.index() != f ? (u.fadeOut(a.fadeSpeed), u = u.next().delay(a.slideDelay).fadeIn(a.fadeSpeed)) : (u.fadeOut(a.fadeSpeed), n.delay(a.slideDelay).fadeIn(a.fadeSpeed), u = n), !1
                    }), e(a.prevBtn).click(function (e) {
                        return e.preventDefault(), u.index() != i ? (u.fadeOut(a.fadeSpeed), u = u.prev().delay(a.slideDelay).fadeIn(a.fadeSpeed)) : (u.fadeOut(a.fadeSpeed), l.delay(a.slideDelay).fadeIn(a.fadeSpeed), u = l), !1
                    }), a.autoPlay) {
                    var r = setTimeout(d, a.autoPlayDelay);
                    t.parent().hover(function () {
                        clearTimeout(r)
                    }, function () {
                        r = setTimeout(d, a.autoPlayDelay)
                    })
                }
            };
        return this.each(d)
    }
}(jQuery);

// SmoothScroll for websites v1.2.1
// Licensed under the terms of the MIT license.
// People involved
//  - Balazs Galambosi (maintainer)  
//  - Michael Herf     (Pulse Algorithm)
;
```

And my question is - How to add several(4 exactly) sliders on one page? Cause, if i just clone html code, all sliders are calling the function at the same time and the refresh is looping. Tried to clone function with other variables, but failed. Help please.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to put each instance in an array as it is instantiated, then you can reference each instance independently via its array position.
ie.

```
 var sliderArr = [];

 var _slider = $(".slider").aSlider({
     prevBtn: '.slider-button-prev',
     nextBtn: '.slider-button-next',
     fadeSpeed: 500, // скорость затухания/появления слайда
     autoPlay: true, // автоперелистывание слайдов (true/false)
     autoPlayDelay: 5000, // время показа в слайдах в миллисекундах
     slideDelay: 500
 });

sliderArr.push(_slider);
```

Then to access the methods and props of that instance:

```
sliderArr[0].yourMethod();
```

If you had a second instance, you would access it the same way:

ie.

```
 sliderArr[1].yourMethod();
```